# Adding category to video Vimeo API using c# WebClient

Tags: c#, json, webclient, vimeo, vimeo-api

I am trying to add a category to a Vimeo video via their API. In the [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/features/categories), it says we can do this through a put request.

```
PUT  https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{video_id}/categories
[
    {
        "category": "animation"
    },
    {
        "category": "2D"
    }
]
```

I assumed that we had to pass data in json (looking at the given example) and passed the categories through a `WebClient()` object. Here is my code:

```
//add categories to video
//string category_uri = "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/" + video_id + "/categories";
WebClient wb_category = new WebClient();
wb_category.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer" + vc.AccessToken);
wb_category.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
string file_category = "[{ \"category\": \"personal\"  }]";
var asByteArrayContent_cat = wb.UploadString("https://api.vimeo.com/videos/" + video_id + "/categories", "PUT", file_category);
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I tried removing the line `wb_category.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");` as well but it gave me the same error. Can anyone help me to correctly send a request to add a category to video? I don't to use `WebClient()` only. Any other class would be ok too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your authorization header needs a space between `bearer` and the token! The line should look like the following:

`wb_category.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + vc.AccessToken);`

This is a very common mistake, I've been thinking about throwing a unique error message for it.

Comment: I'm afraid this didnt make a difference, I already use the header without a space for the thumbnail upload and it works fine.

Comment: Can you contact Vimeo via vimeo.com/help/contact and reference this conversation? The authorization header without a space between bearer and the token is explicitly rejected, so something else is likely happening. An actual log of the request/response cycle (using charles proxy, fiddler, runscope, etc) will help tremendously too.

Comment: Okay,  will do.  I'll check with fiddler.

Comment: Had the same problem, seems this is an issue in the APi